# rails - link_to same page but with anchor -> no reload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I want to use

```
link_to 'Cancel', edit_project_path(@project, url_options)
```

to cancel the edit and go back to the edit page.

I use [jQuery UI Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) for a tabbed edit page. Each tab has it's own form and submit/cancel buttons.

When I click a Cancel link I want to go back to the *active tab*. So I set

```
url_options = {:anchor => active_tab_id}
```

The problem is: the page doesn't reload because of the anchor.
Adding `data-no-turbolink` *does not* help:

```
link_to 'Cancel', edit_project_path(@project, url_options), :data => {:no_turbolink => true}
```

Comment: I don't think this is the best way to handle a cancel button, why would you want to reload the page instead of just resetting the form fields to their original values?

Comment: The [ruby on rails getting started](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) use a Back link. A simple reset button is a bit more difficult, because there are some "incompatible" form elements (e.g. jQuery Chosen, and a Gantt chart) and also some JS logic... so the savest and simplest way would be AFAIK a reload.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way to do it is with javascript.

Add custom data attribute to the link:

```
link_to 'Cancel', edit_project_path(@project, url_options), :data => { :reload => true }
```

Then put this javascript somewhere, for example in app/javascripts/reload_hash.js

```
    $(function(){
        $('a[data-reload="true"').on('click', function(e) {
            window.location = $(e.target).attr('href');
            window.location.reload(true);
        });
    });
```

Comment: I was hoping that there is a cleaner solution that don't involve JavaScript. Anyway, thanks Alex, this solves the problem.

Comment: @jakob no problem, hope I understood your requirements correctly

Comment: This throws an error in Safari Version 8.0 (10600.1.25.1): Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[data-reload="true"

Answer (score 13):

try using
`<%=link_to("Cancel", edit_project_path(@project, url_options), method: :get)%>`
this helped me better

Comment: adding ```method: :get``` worked for me. page reloaded on the request